# Injecting dependencies using annotations in Symfony

Tags: php, spring, symfony

I come from a Spring/Java background and i'm learning Symfony/PHP. It's amazingly similar and i love it.

In Spring we can `@Autowire` dependencies. What is the equivalent of that in Symfony? I want to inject my dependencies using annotations. And i dont want to specify that in an xml or yml.

For example:

```
class foo {

        /**
         * @Inject \ABC\XYZ\Dependency
         */
        private $dependency;

        public function abc(){
              $dependency->bar();
        }
};
```

Also (now this just got on my mind now), is it possible to do something like this. Using annotations, declaring a name and scope for the service:

```
/**
 * @Service("someService")
 * @Scope("session / request / ..")
 */
class foo {

        /**
         * @Inject \ABC\XYZ\Dependency
         */
        private $dependency;

        public function abc(){
              $dependency->bar();
        }
};
```

Comment: Check out http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring will be available as of Symfony 2.8: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-service-auto-wiring

Comment: That's cool. But i'm looking for autowiring with annotations. The JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations seems to do that. Will Symfony incorporate anything like that?